# how does logging into myaccount.google.com automatically log you into youtube.com

Tags: encryption, oauth2

1. You sign into myaccount.google.com.
2. Somewhere along the line your browser is redirected to
   `https://accounts.youtube.com/accounts/SetSID?ssdc=1&sidt=<reallyLongBase64>&continue=https://myaccount.google.com/intro&tcc=1`
   probably inside an iframe.
3. Youtube server sets some cookies.
4. You click the youtube icon in myaccount.google.com and you're logged
   in without following the oauth2 flow.

How can this be achieved?

My best guess is that the `sidt=<reallyLongBase64>` parameter is the users id that should be logged in encrypted with a key private to google with an algorithm that takes time into account(so the request wouldn't be repeatable)

Comment: I think there is no need to repeat information here which can be found already on the internet - [How does Google achieve single sign-on between different domains such as YouTube and Gmail?](https://www.quora.com/How-does-Google-achieve-single-sign-on-between-different-domains-such-as-YouTube-and-Gmail).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich 'Google would maintain a central database of login sessions which can be queried with the session identifier by all the other domain servers' I see no references for this answer so I'm skeptical; since sharing a database among different web applications is a bad practice.